# Proof $\int^b_adt_n \int^{t_n}_a dt_{n-1} ...\int^{t_2}_a dt_{1} = \int^b_a dt_1 \int_{t_1}^b dt_2...\int_{t_{n-1}}^b dt_{n}$without step function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The identity of the ordered integral
$$\int^b_adt_n \int^{t_n}_a dt_{n-1} \int^{t_{n-1}}_a dt_{n-2}...\int^{t_2}_a dt_{1}
=
\int^b_a dt_1 \int_{t_1}^b dt_2 \int_{t_3}^b dt_{4}...\int_{t_{n-2}}^b dt_{n-1}\int_{t_{n-1}}^b dt_{n}$$
could be relatively easier be shown with the usage of theta function.

However, is there a way to proof the identity without using theta function/(Heaviside step function), such as some sort of homology or bijection?

Comment: They are both $n$-dimensional integrals over the set $\{t \in \mathbb{R}^n : a \le t_1 \le \cdots \le t_n \le b\}$.

Comment: @angryavian yes, but how to state it rigorously?(i.e. such that they carried the same weight over the same element). Some sort of trivial mapping might be needed.

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti The way I though of it was to use theta/step function to indicating the order, than the identity was simply which integral to absorb the theta/step function. But that way the mapping between n-dimensional integrals wasn't so obvious like angryavian had mentioned.

Comment: @RicardoCavalcanti Thank you for pointing that out. It's been corrected.